# printing last line in a method with puts

Tags: ruby

Given

```
def sayMoo numberOfMoos
  puts 'mooooooo...'*numberOfMoos
  'yellow submarine'
end
```

I am having trouble understanding why

```
x = sayMoo 2
puts x
```

gives me

```
mooooooo...mooooooo...
yellow submarine
```

and

```
sayMoo 2
```

gives me

```
mooooooo...mooooooo...
```

I am hoping someone could explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling the function`puts` moooooos.

The first example `puts` the function's return value, which is yellow submarine, in addition to that.

The second, in contrast, just calls the function.

Answer (score 0):

`puts` is a method displaying given string (or object) to console (by default). Your method is calling it to display 'moooo... mooo', and then returns the result of lastly excuted expression, in this case it returns the string 'yellow submarine'. Hence when you do:

```
x = sayMoo 2
```

You are executing your method, which first displays 'moo' message, and then assign 'yallow submarine' to variable x, which you can use `puts` on to display. If you just do:

```
sayMoo 2
```

method is executed, but the value returned by method is lost and is not being displayed.